# Округление числа до следующего целого числа десятков

Tags: javascript, jquery, числа, округление

Возможно ли в JavaScript округлять числа по следующей схеме:

допустим у вас 100.1, то делаем 110,

если 123.45 то 130,

если 145.04 то 150,

если 196.09 то 200,

если 25 то 30.

Т.е. округление до следующего десятичного целого значения в большую сторону.

Comment: `Math.round(i/10)*10`

Comment: пробовал, не работает) var randNum = 6.25;
var rounded = Math.round(randNum/10)*10;
alert(rounded);

Comment: а результат то какой?:)

Comment: при 12 = 10, возможно исключив дроби и сделав округление в большую сторону получится) при 31 = 30, при 2 = 0)

Comment: ну в большую, Вам надо ceil

Comment: я коммент писал с телефона и был не шибко внимателен =)

Comment: ммм… наверное, стоит поправить заголовок вопроса... Вам ведь нужно не округление до следующего десятичного целого (т.е. 101, 124, 146, 197, 25 - для ваших примеров) а до следующего целого числа десятков.

Comment: поправил) вы правы

Answer (score 4):

Необходимо разделить на 10, округлить в необходимую сторону а потом умножить на 10

```js
let roundTo10 = i => Math.ceil(i/10)*10;

console.log(roundTo10(6.26))
console.log(roundTo10(100.1))
console.log(roundTo10(123.45))
console.log(roundTo10(145.04))
console.log(roundTo10(196.09))
console.log(roundTo10(25))
```

Comment: Либо `let roundTo = (i, round) => Math.ceil(i/round)*round;` и тогда можно указывать округление.